# Is it possible to display a value from a javascript variable in Aframe <a-text>?

Tags: aframe

```
  <html>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.7.7/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script>
      var d=new Date();
    </script>
      <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <a-scene embedded arjs>
          <a-marker preset="hiro">
        <a-text position='-.5 -1 -1.8' rotation='-45 0 0' color='red' value=var d></a-text>
          </a-marker>
          <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I am a beginner to Aframe. I just want to display the value of variable "d" in aframe a-text box. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in a pure js way you could add an id to your text element like so

```
<a-text id="mytext"></a-text>
```

and then amend your script to the following;

```
<script>
   var d = new Date();
   var text = document.querySelector('#mytext')
   text.setAttribute('value', d)
</script>
```

but it would be better to do it in a component as follows

```
<script> 

AFRAME.registerComponent('displaydate', {

  init: function(){

    var d = new Date()
    this.el.setAttribute('value', d)

  }

})

</script>
```

and then attach that component to your text element like so

```
<a-text displaydate></a-text>
```